# Access DOM Content of a specific URL without directly opening the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

How would I go about saving a URL's DOM to a variable without directly opening that page? For example, let's say I have a Chrome extension that allows the user to right click text, search Google, and alert the user with the first result. How would I do this without opening the search results in another tab? Is there any function like `saveDOMContent("http://www.google.com/search?q=test")` (Note: not a real function) that can do this in pure Javascript?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: AJAX can get the contents of a page into a variable, but it can't generally be used across domains.

Comment: @New Let's say there is a website with a certain question that you're dying to know the answer for. Unfortunately, you're too lazy to highlight the question, right click, and click `search google for...`. I am trying to create an extension that, instead of saying `Search Google for...` will say `Return first answer` and will give the user the link to the top result in Google.

Comment: See the answer below, but if the website you are targeting does not allow Cross-origin resource sharing, then you cant do this.

Comment: Cross-origin is usually not problematic in Chrome Extensions; however, many pages, Google included, are dynamic. Just loading the HTML markup might not work for you. You can load it in an iframe in your background page, but that might also not work because some pages detect being iframe'd.

Comment: One more comment. Querying search engines in such a way typically breaks their Terms of Service and can potentially cause problems for the user. Search engines often offer APIs to query them, but they are not free, at least in Google's case. After all, their income stream is in ads they show along search results.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPage(){
    var somediv =$('#somediv');
    var url='someurl';
    var options = {
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            somediv.innerHTML=transport.responseText;
        }
    };
    new Ajax.Request(url,options);
}
```

Try something like this, but can not say the same for some cross domain calls